# Не получается связать данные по схеме многие-ко-многим через объект

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Схема базы данных:
[image: Схема базы данных]
Модель базы:

```
class Supplier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'suppliers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    shipment = db.relationship('Shipment', backref='supplier', lazy='dynamic')


class Shipment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shipments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_supplier = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Supplier.id))
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    thing = db.relationship('Invoice', back_populates='shipment')


class Invoice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invoice'
    shipment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shipments.id'), primary_key=True)
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('thing.id'), primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    shipment = db.relationship('Shipment', back_populates='thing')
    thing = db.relationship('Thing', back_populates='shipment')


class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    shipment = db.relationship('Invoice', back_populates='thing')
```

В базу уже занесён поставщик и несколько предметов, пытаюсь их связать [по инструкции](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object):

```
>>> a1=models.Invoice(amount=2)
>>> a1.thing(models.Thing.query.get(1))
>>> a2=models.Invoice(amount=3)
>>> a2.thing=models.Thing.query.get(2)
```

Сразу же получаю ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1364, "Field 'shipment_id' doesn't have a default value") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO invoice (thing_id, amount) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (1, 2)]

Ещё попытка:

```
>>> a1=models.Invoice(amount=2)
>>> a1.thing=models.Thing.query.get(1)
>>> ship1=models.Shipment.query.get(1) #Загружаю объект "поставка", чтобы связать с поставленным предметом
```

Ошибка:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1364, "Field 'shipment_id' doesn't have a default value") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO invoice (thing_id, amount) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (1, 2)]

В чём может быть дело? Делаю всё строго по инструкции.

Answer (score 1):

Не особо вникал что это за ресурс, но ошибка 
*"Field 'shipment_id' doesn't have a default value"*
намекает что при *INSERT-е* в таблицу *invoice*, не передается значение на столбец  *shipment_id*, видимо является не нулевым, и не содержит значение по умолчанию/автоинкримента

Comment: Ошибка строго специфична для sqlalchemy и связана с тем, что я пытался создать вторую связь, не завершив первую, из-за чего начинал сбоить autoflush механизм. Решение я уже дал на SO - повторяться не охота. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116305/appending-two-or-more-existing-children-to-parent-cause-integrityerror-query-in/37121725#37121725